# jinja2 indentation with gg=G

Tags: indentation

I develop django templates, and I need to indent them with `gg=G`, but jinja2 tags seem to be immune to it. Here is an example of poorly indented, hard to read *if-else* tags:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load my_tags %}
<center>
    <form action="#" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" value="{{ ids }}" name="search_items" size="40"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Search Items">
    </form>
    {% if searching == True %}
    {% if insert_quantity > 0 %}
    <br><i>{{ insert_quantity }} from {{ match_quantity }} matches selected:</i><br>
    {% item_list items %}
    {% else %}
    No such items in database.
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <h2>Item List (10 randomly selected)</h2>
    {% item_list items %}
    {% endif %}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

I have installed `Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax`, but it does nothing. I also use `YouCompleteMe`, which detects and highlights jinja2 syntax (what makes previous plugin redundant?).

Question:
Is it possible to indent those *if-else* (and *for* loops) tags with `gg=G` with some plugin?

Comment: That plugin [just loads the HTML indentation](https://github.com/Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax/blob/master/indent/jinja.vim) (just like the default `htmldjango` filetype which comes with Vim, and works quite well for Jinja2 in my experience)... You will probably have to do this yourself, by copying the HTML indent file, and modify it so that it recognized Django-style blocks. The file is over 1,000 lines, so this is probably more involved than one or two extra lines...

Comment: ... Or, easier, just learn to press a `<Tab>` key after opening a `{% ...` block, an the `<Backspace>` when closing one. This works quite well for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing is to indent them yourself with *tabs* and *spaces*.

There is one project that is almost what you want, [here is a pull request](https://github.com/Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax/pull/10) that someone made with auto-indentation for jinja2 templates (I haven't tested, it can be buggy).